# mouseover, mouseout, click event handler not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code -

```
setEvents:function(a, b){
    if(b) {
         $('#id').mouseover(function(){
            console.log('mouse over')
         })

         $('#id').mouseout(function(){
            console.log('mouseout')
         })

         $('#id').click(function(){
            console.log('click')
         })
    }
}
```

After this function is executed, I expect that the respective handlers will be fired on the events.
But It is not happening. However, if I put a a dbugger in the method, and trigger the handlers after it has attached, it works. That is when I am inside the method it works. But It does not work once the method is executed.

Comment: Put script inside $(function() { });

Comment: And how the `setEvents` function is called? Please provide the whole JS/HTML snippets.

Comment: What is `setEvents` part of, and when is it applied and what is the value of `b`?

Comment: put it in jsfiddle and share the link

Comment: setEvents is part of Backbone View.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind that function to an object, then there must be a call to the declared function in order to register the event handlers for the `#id` element:

- Define the method:

```js
var handler = {
    setEvents:function(a, b){
        if(b) {
             $('#id').mouseover(function(){
                console.log('mouse over')
             })

             $('#id').mouseout(function(){
                console.log('mouseout')
             })

             $('#id').click(function(){
                console.log('click')
             })
        }
    }
}
```

- Call the method using the object reference and passing it your arguments:

```js
handler.setEvents(a, b);
```

*Here you can take a look to a complete [Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmarwen/936kjfgj/).*

Comment: setEvents is part of Backbone View

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r17zw6ch/1)

HTML (example):

```
<div id="id">lala (with #id)</div>
<br/>
<div>lele (without #id)</div>
```

JS:

```
var setEvents = function(a,b){
    if(b){
         $('#id').mouseover(function(){
            console.log('mouse over');
         });

         $('#id').mouseout(function(){
            console.log('mouseout');
         });

         $('#id').click(function(){
            console.log('click');
         });
        }
}

$(function(){
    setEvents(1,1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post full code "how to call setEvents". But i think maybe you didn't call it when DOM is ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Call setEvents

  });
```

Hope it'll help, if it doesn't work, please post more code

Comment: Cant post full code. its huge. setEvents is part of Backbone View